# What's the name for the structure that helps stop the nose wheel in Boeing 747-400?

Tags: boeing-747, aircraft-structures

From my understanding the nose wheel of a Boeing 747 does not have brakes, and as such when it is retracted it is still spinning. However, there are two "plates" that make contact with the wheels and slow them down, eventually stopping them.

I am curious as to whether someone could provide some more information about this structure, especially the name.

See the image below:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called Snubbers or scuff plates. Spinning tires rub against them on retraction.